# Elasricsearch query with filtering and aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index which contains data of simple car advertisement. I made a mapping:

```
"mappings": {
"properties": {
  "brand": {"type": "keyword"},
  "model": {"type": "keyword"},
  "year of production": {"type": "integer"},
  "mileage": {"type": "integer"},
  "color": {"type": "keyword"},
  "engine capacity": {"type": "double"},
  "horse power": {"type": "integer"}, 
  "type of fuel": {"type": "keyword"},
  "condition": {"type": "keyword"},
  "accident history": {"type": "boolean"},
  "price": {"type": "integer"}
  }
}
```

I want to create two queries:

1. Show average mileage of used cars made between 2010 and 2012 year
2. Show the most popular car model made between 2005 and 2007 year with mileage grater than 200000

I tried to create both and here is the result of my try for the first query:

```
GET /gielda/_search?pretty
{ 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "stan": "Used"
  }
}, 
"aggs": {
  "production_ranges": {
    "range": {
      "field": "year of production",
      "ranges": [
        {
          "from": 2010,
          "to": 2012
        }
      ]
    },
    "aggs": {
      "avg_mileage": {
        "avg": {
          "field": "mileage"
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I find out that this query doesn't work correctly. I was looking for the answer in Elastic docs and on Stack, but still I don't know how to mix aggregation with filter or ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html), [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), [avg](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html), and [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "mileage": 10,
  "year of production": 2011
}
{
  "mileage": 30,
  "year of production": 2012
}
{
  "mileage": 20,
  "year of production": 2013
}
{
  "mileage": 200001,
  "year of production": 2005,
  "model": "ABC"
}
{
  "mileage": 400000,
  "year of production": 2006,
  "model": "DEF"
}
{
  "mileage": 400000,
  "year of production": 2008,
  "model": "GHI"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "production_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "year of production",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 2010,
            "to": 2013
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_mileage": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "mileage"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Popular_car_model": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "year of production": {
                  "gte": 2005,
                  "lte": 2007
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "mileage": {
                  "gte": 200000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_sales_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "mileage": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "model",
                "mileage",
                "year of production"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "Popular_car_model": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "top_sales_hits": {
        "hits": {
          "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
          },
          "max_score": null,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "67650682",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_id": "5",
              "_score": null,
              "_source": {
                "year of production": 2006,
                "model": "DEF",
                "mileage": 400000
              },
              "sort": [
                400000
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "production_ranges": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2010.0-2013.0",
          "from": 2010.0,
          "to": 2013.0,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "avg_mileage": {
            "value": 20.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have already upvoted the answer ! and i was here also to answer the question instead i saw your answer and it was same as what wanted to say ;)

Comment: @MikaelAmidi ohh my bad :/ I thought you were the original poster. Anyways, thanks for the upvote :-)

Comment: @ESCoder I checked Your answer and seems like it works properly, but I have a question about the 2nd query. 2nd query returns exact record with _id, model and mileage fields but I'm not sure it returns the most popular model that fulfill the conditions from query. I think the query should filter cars between 2005 and 2007, then filter cars with mileage grater than 200k, count the unique models and than return the name of the model which was the most frequently sold. Maybe I asked the question using wrong sentence.

Comment: @CarbonRK the second query filters car between 2005 and 2007, and cars having mileage greater than 200000. Based on this filtered data, it finds that car that has the highest mileage. I think this is what you expected to get ?

Comment: @ESCoder Nope I expected to get the name of the car model which fulfil the conditions ( years of production and mileage) and appear the most frequently not the exact record with the highest mileage. I think that should clarify your question :-)

Comment: @ESCoder did you give up with the 2nd query? :-)